# How can I the buttons to work in every component that is returned from an array? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if this question has been answered before. I have tried searching for it. I'm not even really sure what to search for to get the answer. I'm a React beginner so any help is much appreciated.

Inside the **listItems** variable, I am returning components for each item in the **items** array, each with a button. I want the buttons of each components to fire the **handleRemove** function. Currently, an error fires in the console : "handleRemove
 is not defined".

```js
var TaskListComponent = React.createClass({
  
  getInitialState : function(){
    return {
      items:["To do item 1","To do item 2","To do item 3"]
    };
  },

  handleRemove : function(){
    console.log("test")
  },
                                          
  render: function(){
    var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item){
      return <li> {item} <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>X</button></li>;
    });
    return(
      <div>
        Child Container
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Eventually I want to be able to get the buttons to remove the corresponding item that is clicked, from the array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Moe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to pass the context to the map method as in the other answer, or you can use the arrow function instead of the usual function. The arrow function will keep your context which has the handleRemove method in it. if you convert your code into this :

```
var listItems = this.state.items.map((item,index) => {
      return <li key={index}> {item} <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>X</button></li>;
    });
```

it will work as you expect. It would help to read more about binding "this" in  [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) compared to usual functions

Comment: Thanks heaps. This answer served best. Any idea on how to have the value / key of the array being clicked get passed to the function so i can console.log the array value in the handleRemove function. I've looked everywhere I can think, I'm not sure what to google either. I think from their I can read and update the state of components.

Comment: you can define your handleRemove as handleRemove : 
function(value){
    console.log(value);
}

and convert your onClick to :
onClick={this.handleRemove.bind(this, item)}
in order to get the current item. if you are not using es6 classes instead of CreateClass, then just do :
onClick={this.handleRemove(item)}

Comment: I end up using onClick{=()=> this.handleRemove(item)}. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the functions inside `.map` are not bound to your component.

You can bind it to your component passing the context as the second argument.

```
var listItems = this.state.items.map(function(item,index){
      return <li key={index}> {item} <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>X</button></li>;
    },this);
```

Also, dont forget to provide a key for each child in the array.

[full working example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46621/)